# Facing issue compiling GWT after upgrading java to openJDK11

Tags: gwt

Getting following exception after upgrading java. I am using gwt 2.9 libraries and ant in our project.Even after adding the dependents jar like ant.jar colt-1.2.0.jar asm-7.1.jar jsinterop-annotations-2.8.2-v20191108.jar base-1.0.0-beta-2.jar tapestry-util-text-4.0.2.jar

```
 [java] Compiling module hashcode
     [java]    Resolving com.google.gwt.core.client.AsyncProvider
     [java]       Found type 'com.google.gwt.core.client.AsyncProvider'
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          Resolving method get
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be more errors to go with this, rather than just this small snippet, but this is probably the best hint:

> `gwt 2.9`

> `jsinterop-annotations-2.8.2-v20191108.jar`

GWT 2.9 no longer ships its own copy of jsinterop-annotations, but instead you should use jsinterop-annotations 2.0.0. From https://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_9_0:

> Able to compile projects with jsinterop-base 1.0.0, elemental2 1.0.0, and jsinterop-annotations 2.0.0. With the exception of @JsAsync and @JsEnum, this brings GWT2 to be compatible across these tools with J2CL.

Looking at the version you have for your copy of jsinterop-annotations and examining [the list of jars in maven central with that name](https://search.maven.org/search?q=jsinterop-annotations), it looks like you're probably using `org.realityforge.com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:2.8.2-v20191108`. Instead, please switch to `com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:2.0.0`.

If you're using the GWT SDK zip download, jsinterop-annotations is already packaged in gwt-user.jar, so you don't need to bring your own.